# Model Binding produces an empty list

Tags: c#, .net-core, model

When I try to send a post request through postman the `TestCases` list produced is empty. What am I doing wrong?

This is what I pass as a form param for `TestCases`

`[{"input_params":[{"value":"Hello World","type":"string"}],"expected_output":"test123123"}, {"input_params":[{"value":"Hello World2","type":"string"}],"expected_output":"test123123"}]`

But the resulting model created has an empty list of `TestCases`

[image]

How to reproduce:

Postman request:

```
    {
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "6f252c2d-adb0-487e-ba68-d32172ebae91",
        "name": "test",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "Create Assignment",
            "request": {
                "method": "POST",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "",
                        "value": "application/json",
                        "type": "text",
                        "disabled": true
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Content-Type",
                        "name": "Content-Type",
                        "value": "application/json",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "urlencoded",
                    "urlencoded": [
                        {
                            "key": "description",
                            "value": "testDesc2",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "test_cases",
                            "value": "[{\"input_params\":[{\"value\":\"Hello World\",\"type\":\"string\"}],\"expected_output\":\"test123123\"}, {\"input_params\":[{\"value\":\"Hello World\",\"type\":\"string\"}],\"expected_output\":\"test123123\"}]",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "TestCases",
                            "value": "TestCases[]=1050&TestCases[]=2000\n",
                            "type": "text",
                            "disabled": true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "{{localhost}}/api/assignment/create",
                    "host": [
                        "{{localhost}}"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "assignment",
                        "create"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ],
    "protocolProfileBehavior": {}
}
```

Controller method:

```
 [HttpPost("create")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Assignment>> CreateAssignment([FromForm] Assignment assignment)
    {
        Debug.Write(assignment);
        return Ok();
    }
```

Model:

```
 public class Assignment : EntityBase
{
    public Assignment()
    {
        this.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("test_cases")]
    [BindProperty(Name = "test_cases")]
    [Required]
    public virtual List<TestCase> TestCases { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Solution> Solutions { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [JsonProperty("created_date")]
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; private set; }
}
```

TestCase model:

```
 public class TestCase : EntityBase
{
    [JsonProperty("input_params")]
    [BindProperty(Name = "input_params")]
    public virtual List<InputParam> InputParams { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("expected_output")]
    [BindProperty(Name = "expected_output")]
    public string ExpectedOuput { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public int AssignmentId { get; private set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Assignment Assignment { get; private set; }
}
```

EntityBase:

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Is that all you're passing it? You will need to supply it a serialized instance of Assignemnt assignement - just sending in the TestCases value will not work.

Comment: @fredrik You mean like this (example from dotnet doc): `selectedCourses[]=1050&selectedCourses[]=2000
`? Can't I send a JSON array instead?

Comment: I have no idea what type of syntax that is. If you call a function that requires an `Assignent` then your JSON has to represent that class, not just one of the properties in it. How else would it know how to deserialize?

Comment: @fredrik it can deserialize properties passed through form data. As you can see, `Description` is mapped just fine. The only issue is with the list.

Comment: Then your question is incomplete. You're not showing the TestCase class and you're not showing the actual request you're sending in.

Comment: On my current platform I cannot open and properly view your images. Please do as the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page details and don't post images.

Comment: Post the code needed to reproduce the issue (postman can generate code in several different languages to reproduce a request as well).

Comment: @Denki can you add the code of your EntityBase

Comment: @sayahimad added

Comment: @Denki we need just your json that you are using for your request not json to reproduce postman

Comment: @sayahimad I am not sending raw json, I am sending parameters through forms, hence why I have given the postman json to import the request.

Comment: When you send things in by form parameters in this manner - json code in them is not parsed. You will need to remake the entire request to json data in the body of the request - no form parameters. Right now it's empty because a string is not a list of test cases.

Comment: @fredrik so I need to sent it as raw json? I will try it in a bit.

Comment: Yes, and you will probably need to change `[FromForm]` to `[FromBody]` in the controller

Comment: @fredrik yes :)

Comment: @Denki i need input_parameter and solution class plz